# Is it correct to use the phrase - "he / she fights on"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Is it correct to use the phrase "he / she fights on" to say that a person is fighting / struggling for a cause?

Comment: I assume this "fighting" is effectively *metaphoric* (he/she isn't *literally* engaging in combat). Sometimes if you want to add a stronger nuance that the struggle is arduous and/or protracted and/or may never end successfully, you might be better using (also figurative) *soldier, battle*, etc. as the verb.

Answer (score -1):

Yes! Pronouns can always be used for generalization.

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: He/she/they/one fights on.